# why am not getting the friend request sent from my facebook app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-app-requests

i want to send invitation to facebook user who is not on my facebook application . i implemented the below code , am getting the dialog and after clicking on send button am getting a success message also but am not getting any notification on facebook .
   i think i have to add some uri Redirect but i don't know where to add this. please help

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("message", "come and play with me if u dare ! ");


    WebDialog requestsDialog = (
            new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(SendInviteToFB.this,
                Session.getActiveSession(),
                params))
                    .setOnCompleteListener(new WebDialog.OnCompleteListener(){
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                        FacebookException error) {
                        if (error != null) {
                            if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                                Toast.makeText(SendInviteToFB.this, 
                                    "Request cancelled", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(SendInviteToFB.this, 
                                    "Network Error", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } else {
                            final String requestId = values.getString("request");
                            if (requestId != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(SendInviteToFB.this, 
                                    "Request sent",  
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(SendInviteToFB.this, 
                                    "Request cancelled", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }   
                    }

                })
                .build();
        requestsDialog.show();
```